# C++ pointer's suitable alignment

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-alignment

[basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2 about allocation functions:

> The pointer returned **shall be suitably aligned** so that it can be
>   converted to a pointer of any complete object type with a fundamental
>   alignment requirement (3.11) and then used to access the object or
>   array in the storage allocated (until the storage is explicitly
>   deallocated by a call to a corresponding deallocation function).

It is a bit inclear. I thought that any pointer to (include the `void*`) type has alignment equal to 8. What is the point of ***The pointer returned shall be suitably aligned so...***? Could you get an example of no suitable aligned pointer?

Comment: What do you mean, any pointer has alignment equal to 8? What makes you think this?

Comment: Can *you* tell us why you think a pointer is always aligned to an 8 byte boundary?

Comment: It speaks about the returned memory, not the pointer to that memory when it gives the alignment guarantee.

Comment: @jthill `printf("%d",(char*)(a+1)-(char*)(a);` What is it?

Comment: @Praetorian Because when I apply `alignof` operator to the type I have not recieved something different from 8.

Comment: What types have you tried it on, and on what platform?

Comment: Please add a citation if you quote. A bit of context would be nice, too.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv That could be an implementation detail, or dependent on the type you're allocating.

Comment: Quote is from [basic.stc.dynamic.allocation]/2

Comment: @AndrewMedico http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/879272754c9b4493

Comment: @DmitryFucintv that code worked only for scalars anyway, I plead caffeine deprivation. Yeah, that's it.

Comment: @Deduplicator operator new returns void*.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You're inspecting the alignment of pointer types. You should be inspecting the types that you're actually `new`ing.

Comment: @AndrewMedico But the quote said that the *pointer* returned shall be a suitable alignment... operator new returns _void*_, so I assume, that void* returned by operator new shall be a suitble aliggment.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv The pointer should be suitably aligned according to the fundamental alignment requirements. Read 3.11, paragraphs 1 and 2 carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Many systems require the dereferenced pointers are aligned to be a multiple of the size of the type. For instance, pointers for `shorts` would be on multiples of 2 bytes, `char` pointers are unrestricted, etc. Not all systems have this requirement, but accesses on unaligned memory on these systems are frequently very slow, and so typically programmers try to keep everything aligned anyways.

You can find the alignment requirement for a type with `alignof`, if you want to poke around on your system. A pointer that isn't aligned properly for any type might be something like `0xFFFF0002`, which wouldn't be aligned for any 4 byte or higher type.

In short, what that documentation is saying is that the memory returned will be aligned for any fundemental type.